# error: opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I was trying to write a camera program by watching an example video, when I finished writing codes , builted it then I got a messagge like at the title.

Comment: if it needs that, your code is outdated. please move on to code, that does not require the deprecated c-api.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open **Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General**, and edit the field **Additional Include Directories** to add these 3 paths (for the headers):

> C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include\opencv
>
> C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include\opencv2
>
> C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include

Comment: This worked for me for opencv3.2.0, VS14 and Windows 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you use Windows operating system. However, I think that I can share my experience in linux system. Wish that can help you.

I have installed opencv 2.4.11 in ubuntu 14.04 and faced the same problem.
All the `#include opencv*` like `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"` got error when compiling C++ files. I figured that in the sys path `/usr/local/include/` there are no `opencv/` or `opencv2/` but only `opencv-2.4.11/`.

The folders `opencv/` and `opencv2/` are under the folder `opencv-2.4.11/`. That is why system cannot recognize them and the subdirectories of them. It is very easy to solve the problem.

Commands like these to make system recognize the paths:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/include/opencv-2.4.11/opencv /usr/local/include/opencv
sudo ln -s /usr/local/include/opencv-2.4.11/opencv2 /usr/local/include/opencv2
```

Tom J Muthirenthi's answer in essential is to link the build directories of opencv which can always work as long as opencv is compiled, no matter whether it is installed to system. In Linux, things are very similar.

Dmitry Spikhalskiy's answer is very useful when the installation or compilation of opencv gets wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In case of linux system you should check availability of "opencv2/core/core_c.h" on /usr/local/include or /usr/include path. If you have no this file - try reinstall opencv according to the [official instructions](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html).